# Program to creating notes as a Tree

Tags: json, xml, yaml

I need a program that can be used to create notes and store them as a tree with nodes. What does this mean?

This means that I can write something like this:

```
Day 1
  Task 1
    Action 1
  Task 2
    Action 1
    Action 2
Day 2
```

There will be labels (as shown above) and then a lot of notes attached with the label. The notes shall appear in a separate textbox.

Now I can collapse the entire tree or expand the portions that I need. The data itself could be stored in XML format or JSON or YAML, does not matter.

Does such a program actually exist?

Comment: For which operating system ? Can it be saved in HTML ?

Comment: @quantum231, Price requirements?

Comment: Price should be free open source, or cost less than 100£.

Comment: @quantum231, Isn't "free open source" also less than $100?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CherryTree**

https://github.com/giuspen/cherrytree

https://github.com/giuspen/cherrytree/releases (Assets) to install.

A hierarchical note taking application, featuring rich text and syntax highlighting, storing data in a single XML or SQLite file.

XML = File / Export / Export to CherryTree Document / All the Tree / XML, Not Protected (.ctd)

[image]